# Last week is missing in prolific interactive material calendar view

Tags: android, calendar, material-design, android-calendar, material-components-android

I'm using a material calendar library which was developed by prolific interactive in my android application. In calendar view, I noticed that in some months, the last week is missing. 
[image]

I have checked this with different mobile devices and Android versions, but I get this issue only in some devices. Currently I'm facing this issue in OPPO F5. Below is the xml code of the calendar view.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="100dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/balance_arrow_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shadow"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circular_arrow"/>


        <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView 
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/balance_calendar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/balance_arrow_right"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/balance_arrow_left"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:mcv_arrowColor="@android:color/white"
            app:mcv_firstDayOfWeek="monday"
            app:mcv_headerTextAppearance="@style/headerTextAppearance"
            app:mcv_selectionColor="#f4c842"
            app:mcv_weekDayTextAppearance="@style/weekDayTextAppearance"
            app:mcv_showOtherDates="defaults"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/balance_arrow_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_shadow"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:rotation="180"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_circular_arrow" />
```

Did anyone face the same issue? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting app:mcv_showOtherDates="all" ?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to display other months dates so I can't use that option

Comment: Yes, removing that option is same as app:mcv_showOtherDates="defaults". Both do not show other months dates

Comment: is the padding bottom of Relative layout causing the issue, try reducing it.

Comment: if this doesn't help please send the code of your complete layout so that I can try it myself.